# Export objects vs functions NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, object

### Export Objects `{}` vs Export function

I'm developing an exercise application, I came across to the question **When do I need to exports an object `{}` instead of a function class?**

**Scenario example:**

I'm building a simple authentication `module` using the object style.

```
// file auth.js
module.exports = {

    login: function() {
       // code login
    },

    logout: function() {
      // code logout
    },

    register: function() {
      // code register
    }
}
```

Here I'm using the **anonymous function** style

```
module.exports = function() {

        return {
            login: function() {
               // code login
            },

            logout: function() {
              // code logout
            },

            register: function() {
              // code register
            }
         }
    }
```

---

### Requiring

When I want to **require** this module I just do:

```
var auth = require('auth');

auth.login(); // trigger login function via object
auth().login() // trigger login function via function
```

It will work with both the approaches, but I'm confused to choose which fit better and why.

### Questions

- How do you understand in your design of a module, when is appropriate to exports, an **object**, **anonymous function**, **named function to Instantiate**?
- Which are the difference and how the require method behave, when requiring these **functions** or **Objects** ?

Comment: `It will work with both the approaches, ` - No it will not. For the second method to work, you need to do `var auth = require('auth')();`

Comment: Yes sorry, You are right just correcting that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do you understand in your design of a module, when is appropriate to exports, an object, anonymous function, named function to Instantiate?

- true minimalists aim to export a single function if that will suffice. This is based on the scope of your module and assumes a small and focused purpose.
- Export an object of related functions when you need a set of functions to have a meaningful set of functionality. For example, a `tempConversion` module might have both `cToF` and `fToC` functions.
- If you are doing OO, exporting the constructor function is fine.
- a closure function that returns the real payload (which can be an object or a function) is useful for configuration options. For example `var tip = require('computeTip')(18);` could store 18 in closure and return a function that would calculate 18% tip when called with a number.

Here's a **rule of thumb**: if you export only one named function a la `require('average').average(listOfNumbers)`, it's redundant, so just export the `average` function directly to make it more concise. If you have more than one function you want to expose, use an object whose properties are the functions.

> Which are the difference and how the require method behave, when requiring these functions or Objects ?

- There are no differences. `require` has a single behavior that accommodates each of these techniques.

Comment: Thanks for point me on the right direction, I'm just not sure in your point `true minimalists aim to export a single function if that will suffice` can you do an example of single function :) Really appreciated

Comment: Sure. substack is one of the most prolific authors on npm and a staunch minimalist. His arg-parsing library minimist does this. https://github.com/substack/minimist/blob/e2563e462be40c344c6c65b7cde85091fe261976/index.js#L1

Comment: Thanks a lots, this example make sense, but I'm seeing that he's passing 2 arguments to the module, if I don't need any on my module, it always make sense to pass a `function` like he does? I will leave open this thread for a while for see other answers, you are candidate for correct answer.

Comment: He's not **passing** 2 arguments, he's **accepting** 2 arguments from his callers.

Comment: Yes that's right! Thanks for the rule of thumb! I think I got it :) I really appreciated your help.

Answer (score 3):

In both your examples you actually return an object and not a function class. In the second case you get the object by executing the function. In order to use the function as a class you should return a function which acts as the constructor, and then instantiate with the new operator.

That being said, I would prefer an object over a class if I consider my module as a singleton, something that would be common to every file that would include it. An example would be a module that implements a common access layer to my database.

A class makes more sense if you intent to instantiate it multiple times. An example would be a specific model class for your database schema, like a User class.

Comment: Thanks a lots for your answer, it make sense. So in this case an `Auth` module will make sense to use an object? Because it should be a singleton and no need to be instated multiple times. Only the methods will act accordantly to the parameters passed I'm right?

Comment: @Fabrizio Correnct, you can use an object for an Auth module.